# Algorithm for root function $[2^{n-1}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, inverse

I am attempting to convert this function $[2^{n-1}]$ into a root function to return original value. Thus far all my attempts have ended in abject failure.

Base    : 1 2 3 4  5  6  7  8   9

Result : 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256

Trying to get a algorithm to take the Returns number and revert it into base.

Thanks in advance.

Finally figured it out, in excel format it is "=Log(Result,2)+1"

Comment: If you've answered your own question, post it below and mark it as accepted. By the way, we usually call this the *inverse* of the function.

Comment: Thanks for terminology clarification, and assistance in utilizing the website. @Sharkos

Answer (score 1):

(To cut down on unanswered questions.) As you seem to have determined, the following are equivalent: $$y=2^{n-1}\\n-1=\log_2y\\n=1+\log_2y$$ $f(x)=1+\log_2x$ is the desired inverse function, then.